# Crear una imagen a partir de un dataframe usando Python

Tags: python, imagen

estoy intentando crear una imagen de un tamaño especifico de pixeles y dibujar en ella varias trayectorias que tengo ordenadas en un dataframe por coordenadas x y. Un ejemplo de como luce el dataframe con 2 trayectorias seria asi:

```
In [60]: df
Out[60]: 
TRACK_ID     x            y                        
1          16.130       8.993
1          15.817       8.699
1          16.076       8.712
1          16.176       8.191
1          16.486       8.106
2          16.308       8.500
2          16.270       8.441
2          16.042       8.474
2          15.966       8.487
2          15.882       8.431
2          15.869       8.419
```

Después, uso PIL para generar la imagen:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
img = Image.new("RGB", (512,512), "black")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

coords = ['x','y']
dotSize = 2

for (x,y) in coords:
    draw.line([x,y,x+dotSize-1,y+dotSize-1], fill="red")

img.show()
```

Esto funciona bien para puntos (x,y) pero debo ingresar uno por uno, Como puedo hacer para ingresar mis columnas completas como trayectorias independientes? Existe una forma mas simple de pasar mis columnas a una imagen binaria? Gracias

Comment: Hola Jonathan, para aclararme un poco.. ¿Lo que deseas es dibujar una linea que una los puntos correspondientes a cada valor de la columna TRACK_ID?, es decir, una linea que una los puntos con valor 1, otra con los puntos de valor 2, etc,  todos en la misma imagen. ¿Has considerado usar matplotlib, crear una gráfica y guardarla como imagen sin ejes ni etiquetas? Con el código que muestras, si le pasa tuplas de puntos (`[(12.5,  6.2), (13.4, 7.2), (14, 7.95)]`) lo que dibujas son líneas de la longitud de dotSize por cada punto.

Comment: Hola, si, en el ejemplo serian 2 trayectorias distintas (TRACK_ID) y sus coordenadas correspondientes. Usando matplotlib se puede definir el cuadro por pixeles especificos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `pandas.groupby` para obtener cada trayectoria en función del valor de la columna `TRACK_ID`. Hecho esto solo tienes que iterar sobre el objeto `groupby` y por cada grupo crear un iterable de tuplas `(x, y)` para pasárselo a `draw.line`. Esto ultimo puedes hacerlo con `zip`.

Si quieres, puede crear otro iterable para dibujar cada grupo con un color diferente. Una opción muy simple es crear un mapa de colores cíclico usando `itertool.cycle`. Puedes usar valores RGB o  HSL para definir los colores, no obstante, suele ser más simple usar [nombres de colores HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp)(mas información en http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageColor.html#color-names)

Por ejemplo, vamos a crear un dataframe similar al tuyo (se van a distanciar más los puntos para que sea más descriptivo) y vamos a crear una linea para cada trayectoria de un color diferente:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw


data = {"TRACK_ID": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
        "x": [10, 75, 50, 300, 400, 12, 17, 27, 30, 45, 40, 15, 65, 400, 19, 45, 234],
        "Y": [10, 75, 50, 300, 500, 10, 105, 200, 100, 305, 420, 17, 47, 176, 20, 165, 375]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index("TRACK_ID", inplace = True)


# Lo anterior es solo para crear un DataFraem como el tuyo,
# lo importante es lo siguiente:
tracks = df.groupby("TRACK_ID")

img = Image.new("RGB", (512,512), "black")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
colors = itertools.cycle(("Red", "Chartreuse", "DarkOrange", "DarkMagenta"))

for t, group in tracks:
    coords = tuple(zip(group.x, group.Y))
    draw.line(coords, width=2, fill=next(colors))


img.show()
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los colores también los puedes definir en un diccionario, siendo la clave cada valor de `TRACK_ID`, de forma que puedes definir con precisión con que color se dibuja cada trayectoria.

Comment: Ese es exactamente lo que estaba buscando, muchas gracias como siempre excelente explicacion, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Veamos, en primer lugar, cuando haces esto:

```
dotSize = 2
for (x,y) in coords:
    draw.line([x,y,x+dotSize-1,y+dotSize-1], fill="red")
```

Estás prácticamente dibujando cada punto, en realidad, lineas con un desplazamiento de un pixel por cada coordenada que tengas. Lo que en realidad deberías hacer, es, dibujar la linea completa con la lista de tuplas de coordenadas, es decir invocar `draw.line` con dicha lista. Algo así a modo de ejemplo

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
img = Image.new("RGB", (512,512), "black")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

coords = [
  (100, 100),
  (150, 200),
  (300, 100),
  (400, 300),
]

dotSize = 2
draw.line(coords, width=dotSize, fill="red")
img.show()
```

Esta sería la salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Entonces tendría que transformar mis columnas a tuplas y con eso bastaría para graficar mis dataframe no es asi?

Comment: Si efectivamente, si tus coordenadas obviamente representan los distintos puntos de una linea, esta podría ser una solución.